# PHP Exits When I Try to Connect to a Database Using MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been developing a website recently, and I came across an error. When I tried to do `print_r(error_get_last());` It output some text about mysql not being supported anymore, and to use MySQLi. I was all for it. When I edited my database class to support MySQLi, it exits every time it tries to connect. I have put `echo 'hi<br />';` before and after the `mysqli` function, and a `or trigger_error("Error: " . print_r(error_get_last()));` at the end of it, but all it outputs is `hi`, and nothing else. My database is created in phpMyAdmin, and has all the correct permissions, but it just cannot connect. This is my connection code:

```
echo 'hi<br />';
$this->db = mysqli($host, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or trigger_error("Error: " . print_r(error_get_last()));
echo 'hi<br />';
$this->connect_start = microtime(true);
if ($this->db->connect_errno > 0) die ($this->debug(true));
```

It is in the constructor of a class that looks like this:

```
function db($host, $dbname, $dbpass, $dbuser)
```

and it is called like this:

```
$db = new db($host, $dbname, $dbpass, $dbuser);
```

Comment: `$this->db = mysqli()` should be `$this->db = new mysqli()`. `mysqli` is not a function, it's a class.

Comment: There should be a class with name db and then you can create the instance of that class using new keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$this->db = mysqli()
```

to

```
$this->db = new mysqli()
```

mysqli is not a function, it's a class. If you had error reporting on you'd get a message like this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysqli()

That's the reason why the rest of your code isn't executed, the execution stops right there.

Also note that `new mysqli()` will never return `false`, so your `or ...` part becomes useless. If you want to check for connection errors you have to check `$this->db->connect_error` after the connection attempt.